# How long for Firebase Remote Config to push?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

How long does it take for a remote config to push? I have the following code, which continues to print false and the old value for at least a few minutes after pushing a new update on the web.

```
remoteConfig.fetchWithCompletionHandler { (status, error) -> Void in
    if (status == FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus.Success) {
        print("Config fetched.")
        print(self.remoteConfig.activateFetched())
        print(self.remoteConfig.configValueForKey("my_key").stringValue)
    } else {
        print("Config not fetched.")
    }
}
```

Comment: it should show you new notification maximum 5 second. id your internet connection is fast. if  your internet connection is fast then hosting problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default behavior is to cache for 12 hours, according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/ios). The function

```
fetchWithExpirationDuration(expirationDuration: NSTimeInterval, completionHandler: FIRRemoteConfigFetchCompletion?)
```

specifies the cache duration. At first glance, I thought the duration was a timeout on the network request — in fact, it's a timeout on the cache. If you use this with a short duration, the values will reload as quickly as you set the cache to expire.