# Retrieve data from firebase and store it in variable

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on a project in which I want a feature, message us on WhatsApp and for that, I used WhatsApp API using intent.
in 'message us on WhatsApp' feature I'm using 2-3 different numbers and storing it in the list and using random() method to retrieve that number from the list, as I want whenever a user uses that feature he/she has to connect with a different number every time.
but now I want to change those numbers which are stored inside the list.

So how can I change those numbers without changing the actual code every time?

I know it can be achieved using firebase, but I don't have too much idea about firebase.

I can only upload simple text and images on firebase and retrieve them. but how can I upload all these numbers on firebase? and how I can change them every time within a minute
the code I did is like this

```
public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CardView wpicon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        Util.blackIconStatusBar(DashBoard.this, R.color.white);
        wpicon = findViewById(R.id.cardview1);

        wpicon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        String num;
        String text;
        num = ";
        text = "I'm interseted in your service";
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("+91");
        list.add("+91");
        Random random = new Random();
        String rando = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.cardview1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i = intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + rando + "&text=" + text));
                startActivity(i);
                break;
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the shared code?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this with Firebase is by using [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config). The idea is generally simple. The remote config represents a list of keys and values. You have to list your data from the Firebase console and publish it. It will be immediately available to your users.

Comment: It sounded like OP wanted them changed within a minute. Remote config settings are not updated immediately, more like every [12 hours by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583550/how-long-for-firebase-remote-config-to-push)

Comment: Anything uploaded through the Firebase Remote config is immediately available to all users of the app.

Comment: Available, yes, but the app will not automatically update its values immediately without also using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime).

Comment: the given solution is 100% Working. thanks for suppport